# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS | Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media while trying to dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, usb, live-usb

here is the tutorial i went through to dual boot: [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSVV_EoApdo)

here is the steps i did to get where i am now:

- resized a partition for ubuntu to install into
- turned of fast startup from this [thing](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html)
- downloaded the ubuntu ISO
- created a bootable usb stick with [rufus](https://rufus.ie/)
- booted from usb stick
- accidently pressed **try ubuntu without installing** or something like that from the **GNU GRUB**
- tried to download ubuntu from the inside
- the installation type that i chose is **something else** because i want to dual boot between ubuntu and win10
- created a swap area (don't know what is it for) and an **Ext4** partition with "/" as mount point
- then i pressed install now but it gave me a warning of not having an efi partition of some sort (but in the tutorial it went smoothly for him)
- pressed continue without creating an efi partition
- then filled the rest of the stuff and waited for ubuntu to complete installation
- then the installer crashed...
- it wouldn't close if i tried so i restarted the pc (mind you that the usb stick was still on)
- it showed me the **GNU GRUB** again and i chose to install ubuntu from there
- clicked **erase ubuntu and reinstall** and did the same things
- it finished and told me to restart and everything was fine cause i created the efi partition from the main partition
- it didnt't tell me to remove the usb stick like in the tutorial and showed me the **GNU GRUB** again with **try ubuntu without installation** and **install ubuntu** and **oem install**
- then restarted the pc and removed the usb to see what happens but it just gave me **Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media**
- and now im stuck with ubuntu and don't know how to return to win10

tried to see the boot order but there was just one thing there *assuming its the hdd*

can anyone tell me what to do to return to windows or to dual boot?

any little help is appreciate.
and sorry for the long explanation, and if you need any more explanation just say ^^.

Comment: `it finished and told me to restart and everything was fine cause i created the efi partition from the main partition` - you might want to specify what you mean here. It sounded like you let the auto-partitioner take care of things, but then you note that you created the efi partition (did you create it as FAT32? EFI needs FAT32). For extra troubleshooting, boot into the USB `Try` mode, and list the output of `df -h ; lsblk ; sudo fdisk -l` for reference too.

Comment: @taifwa I appreciate it that you're trying to help but I solved it rn, all I had to to is let the PC boot to the HDD first than the usb stick.

Comment: Fair. You can actually add an "answer" to your own question and accept it ; this is the equivalent of tying up loose ends on a question, which tends to be desirable :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the boot order from the BIOS to boot to the HDD than the usb stick then it booted to Ubuntu and re installed everything. After the restart I removed the usb stick and **GNU GRUB** was there to choose from windows or Ubuntu.